# Universal cover of a riemannian manifold inherits the metric of space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

I read on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniversalCover.html that any property of X can be lifted to its universal cover, as long as it is defined locally, the riemannian metric of a manifold $(X)$ is defined locally, so the I want to think that the unviersal cover have a metric deffined by the metric of $X$, but I don't know how to prove this or where to find it. If you can give me some book that help me with this would be very helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: It would help to have a little more context here, to know what kind of an answer you're looking for. The short answer is that if $\pi$ denotes the canonical projection and $g$ the metric on $X$, then the induced metric on the universal cover is just the pullback $\pi^* g$.

Comment: Oooo now its kind of obvious, but I would like a book that can give me more context about this. (Specially the part of the Riemannian metric)

Comment: It depends on what you're looking for exactly. There's not much more to say about this particular fact, but covering spaces come up in Riemannian geometries in important ways, like the classification of constant curvature spaces and Hadamard's Theorem. Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds* at least mentions some results along these lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(M,g)$ is a Riemmanian manifold and $p: \tilde M \to M$ is a covering space projection, then in particular $p$ is a local diffeomorphism.  (Note: $\tilde M$ does not need to be the universal cover.  It can be any cover, since all we'll use is that $p$ is a local diffeomorphism.)

Then for $x \in \tilde M$, the differential of $p$ is an isomorphism $p_*: T_x \tilde M \tilde\rightarrow  T_{p(x)} M$, which allows us to define an inner product $\tilde g_x$ on $T_x \tilde M$ from the inner product $g_{p(x)}$ on $T_{p(x)} M$.

Explicitly: $\tilde g_x(Y,Z) := g_{p(x)}(p_*Y,p_*Z)$.

Doing so for each $x\in \tilde M$ defines a metric $\tilde g$ on $\tilde M$, whose smoothness follows from smoothness of $g$ and the fact that $p$ is a local diffeomorphism.